# How do I type a custom User model manager for mypy in Django?

Tags: python, django, mypy

I'm using Django 4.1.7 with django-stubs 1.16.0, and mypy 1.1.1.

I created a custom user manager for my User model like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager


class MyUserManager(UserManager):
    def delete_test_data(self):
        return self.filter(test_data=True).delete()

class User(AbstractUser):
    test_data = models.BooleanField()
    ...

    objects = MyUserManager()
```

Everything works as expected, but when I run mypy on this, it complains with:

```
models.py:32: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "MyUserManager[User]", base class "AbstractUser" defined the type as "UserManager[AbstractUser]")  [assignment]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a mypy bug? Bad types defined in django-stubs? Is there a way to type this without forcing mypy to ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying that my manager is for `AbstractUser` seems to have worked:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager, AbstractUser

class MyUserManager(UserManager[AbstractUser]):
    ...
```